# I'm learning opencv in python using a book and i'm getting this error :only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So I'm trying to draw a histogram using opencv
i followed very closely to the book and i'm getting this `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I tried finding the solution but i don't really understand.

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

file_src = 'src.jpg'

img_src = cv2.imread(file_src, 1)
img_hst = np.zeros([100, 256], dtype="uint8")
rows, cols = img_hst.shape

hdims = [256]
hranges = [0, 256]
hist = cv2.calcHist([img_src], [0], None, hdims, hranges)

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(hist)
for i in range(0, 255):
    v = hist[i]
    cv2.line(img_hst, (i, rows), (i, rows - rows * (v / max_val)), (255, 255, 255))

cv2.imshow('dst', img_src)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks for helping